# How to backreference a calculated column value in another column during an INSERT query on Postgres? (query-runtime temporary variable assignment)

Tags: sql, postgresql

In MySQL there's some helpful syntax for doing things like `SELECT @calc:=3,@calc`, but I can't find the way to solve this on PostgreSQL

The idea would be something like:

```
SELECT (SET) autogen := UUID_GENERATE_v4() AS id, :autogen AS duplicated_id;
```

returning a row with 2 columns with same value

EDIT: Not interested in conventional \set, I need to do this for hundreds of rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select id, id as duplicated_id
from (select UUID_GENERATE_v4() AS id
     ) x
```

Postgres does not confuse the `select` statement by allowing variable assignment.  Even if it did, nothing guarantees the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`, so you still would not be sure that it worked.

Comment: Thanks! nice! The problem is when you are already joining a lot of  tables. Think that this is just a simplification, my real need is more complex and verbose, so it makes this solution a bit more noisy

Comment: To be honest my need is an INSERT  but for simplicity's sake I jut used the example  on a SELECT, since I seem to remember there was no difference on MySQL for the @:= facility

Comment: @Whimusical . . . Just use a CTE with your current logic.  Your code is specifically not guaranteed to work in MySQL either, by the way.

Comment: curious because I used in production without any troubles for months. I guess I am lucky

Comment: @Whimusical . . . As explicitly stated in the MySQL documentation "For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1 evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html)